# Joining formatted lists

Tags: powershell

I am trying to join two formatted lists of information:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem | Format-List Caption
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Processor | Format-wide Name,Manufacturer,MaxClockSpeed
```

When I use these two commands I get the following output (Whitespace included):

```
Caption : Microsoft Windows 8 Pro





Name          : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
Manufacturer  : GenuineIntel
MaxClockSpeed : 2201
```

Is there any easy way to join these two lists, thus reducing the whitespace and getting somewhat the same spacing between the colon and the strings?

Comment: You can't really do much once you've passed your data through `Format-Object`. Anytime you call a `format-*` cmdlet, think of it as the endpoint for your data - you've lost the ability to do anything meaningful with it once it's formatted for that output. Compose a custom object, then format *that*.

Comment: That makes sense. Didn't look at it like the endpoint for the data. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new object based on the properties selected from each wmi class:

```
$os = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object Caption
$processor = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Processor | Select-Object Name,Manufacturer,MaxClockSpeed

New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Caption = $os.Caption
    ProcessorName = $processor.Name
    ProcessorManufacturer = $processor.Manufacturer
    ProcessorMaxClockSpeed = $processor.MaxClockSpeed
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Adding a Format-List pipe after that makes the output perfect.  However, I don't fully understand hwo the PSObject works. Is there anywhere I can read more about it (simple explanation)?

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/19/create-custom-objects-in-your-powershell-script.aspx